# Jacksonparser parser issue: Can not deserialize instance of <OBJECT> out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, jackson

The snippet of JSON is as below :

```
"text": {"paragraph": [
                "For use in manufacturing only.",
                [
                    {
                        "styleCode": "bold",
                        "content": "CAUTION:"
                    },
                    "Certain components of machine feeds"
                ],

                "Precautions such as the follow"
            ]}
```

As you can see this is a mix of strings and objects, and I encounter "Can not deserialize instance of com.example.json.Paragraph out of START_ARRAY token"

Anyway around this?

My class definition is as shown below, the Content object is for 'stylecode' and 'content' attributes.

```
public class Paragraph {

    private String contentStr;    

    private Content content;
```

The Content object is as shown below,

```
public class Content {  

    private String styleCode;

    private String content;
```

Comment: I understand that this is an array since it begins with '[', but is this kind of parsing possible besides I have no control on the json side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your objects should be like this-
Content class

```
public class Content {
    private String styleCode;
    private String content;
    private String data;

    //Getter Setter Methods
}
```

Paragraph class

```
public class Paragraph {
    private List<Content> contentList;

    //Getter Setter Method
}
```

And the deserializer class should be

```
public class ParagraphDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Paragraph> {

    @Override
    public Paragraph deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);

        JsonNode text = node.get("text");
        JsonNode paragraphs = text.get("paragraph");

        List<Content> contentList = new ArrayList<Content>();

        for(int i = 0; i < paragraphs.size(); i++) {

            JsonNode p = paragraphs.get(i);

            Content c = new Content();

            String data = "", styleCode = "", content = "";

            try {
                data = p.textValue();
            } catch(Exception ignore) {
            }

            if(data == null) {
                for(int j = 0; j < p.size(); j++) {
                    JsonNode o = p.get(j);

                    try {
                        data = o.textValue();

                        if(data != null) {
                            c.setData(data);
                        }
                    } catch(Exception ignore) {
                    }

                    if(data == null) {
                        styleCode = o.get("styleCode").textValue();
                        content = o.get("content").textValue();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                c.setData(data);
            }

            c.setContent(content);
            c.setStyleCode(styleCode);  

            contentList.add(c);
        }

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.setContentList(contentList);
        return p;
    }
}
```

I have tested it against your given json snippet, works for it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Rane!